# Semantic UI: How to deal with extra paddings?

Tags: html, css, padding, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a modal using Semantic UI, and I uploaded a sample [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whg5ftov/5/) in order to give more details about the code:

```
<div id="modal" class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="ui menu">
    <div class="ui header item">
      Title
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
    <a class="active item">
      Item
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui segment">
    <p>
    my content here
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In fact, there is  three extra paddings:

1. One upper the top menu (caused by the 'close icon')
2. The second between the top menu ("Title") and the secondary pointing menu ("Item": downside)
3. And the last one, between the secondary pointing menu ("Item") and paragraph ("my content here").

These paddings are unnecessary in my case, and they shouldn't be applied to the UI.

I'm new to Semantic UI, and I don't know exactly what I'm missing in order to escape these paddings.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/938xhtyg/

Comment: @ManojKumar Yeah, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.